# Parallax Scrolling Choppy; C# Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D Platformer to get my feet wet with making a dynamic 2d game in Unity, and I've encountered a hiccup with my parallax scrolling setup for the game. It has 4 separate layers with one background that moves. It's choppy, and the problem looks like this: https://streamable.com/26hx1

The script the parallax effect is written with is here: https://codeshare.io/5Rnd34

The issue with the parallax scrolling background is not related to the movement of the character. I have tried different methods of moving my character, to no avail *(currently using AddForce)*.

It may be due to the CameraFollow script: https://codeshare.io/2EMxON

Thanks for your help, tell me if you need any more description/info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My parallax smoothing effect multiplier was too dramatic, lagging the parallax effect on my end. I put down the smoothing, and now it works flawlessly.

The script was also incorrect.